# How to use @SerializedName alternate field in GSON to deserialize nested object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, jsonpath

In deserialization I am trying to map different JSON nodes to a single field using GSON.

I have the next field in a class:

```
private List<MyObjects> pages;
```

Incoming json may be:

```
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "pageNumber": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or

```
{
  "pages": {
    "list": [
      {
        "pageNumber": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to map the array of pages to the *pages* class field using this:

```
@SerializedName(value = "pages", alternate = "pages.list")
public List<MyObjects> pages;
```

but it doesnt work.

It seems that GSON does not support this. But maybe someone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

For question

> How to use alternate field in GSON?

the answer lies in the docs that I have partly copied here (and maybe you already know all or part of this).

For question

> It seems GSON doesnt support this. But maybe someone know why?

Yes, maybe some Gson designer could answer to that. Personally I do not see any reason why it could not support `JSONPath` in that annotation attribute. Anyway I will concentrate to the question in the title.

This just is not how `@SerializedName.alternate` works now.  If you take a look on the [Gson API specs](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html):

> public abstract String[] alternate
>
> Returns:
>       the alternative names of the field when it is deserialized

*(so names not paths)*

> Here is an example of how this annotation is meant to be used:
>
> ```
> public class MyClass {
>     @SerializedName("name") String a;
>     @SerializedName(value="name1", alternate={"name2", "name3"}) String b;
> ```

and

> While deserializing, all values specified in the annotation will be
>   deserialized into the field. For example:
>
> ```
> MyClass target = gson.fromJson("{'name1':'v1'}", MyClass.class);
> assertEquals("v1", target.b);
> target = gson.fromJson("{'name2':'v2'}", MyClass.class);
> assertEquals("v2", target.b);
> target = gson.fromJson("{'name3':'v3'}", MyClass.class);
> assertEquals("v3", target.b);
> ```

In other words - when deserializing - it simply maps differently named fields to be deserialized to some one and the same field. It does not map field in alternate **paths** in `Json` source. It might be a nice feature, though.

So in the API doc example all fields that have name ["name1", "name2", "name3"] will be deserialized to `MyClass` field `b`. What it does not do - as I have understood - is to deserialize any nested Json object to that annotated field.

At the moment those two `pages` fields just seems like different objects to Gson.

Comment: I've found a solution, instead of field **List<MyObjects> pages** use **JsonElement pages** and then check pages.isJsonObject or pages.isJsonArray

Comment: @SbLon Perhaps you could create an answer - with example code - from your finding it might help somebody else.